# What are some alternatives to admin_menu module for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

Is there an alternative to the admin_menu module for drupal 7? I like the fact that it contains all the site links in the dropdowns, but it seems to conflict with some of the modules I have installed and I have run into issues with this module. I'm not sure why its such a heavy module. I guess it has to transverse the entire admin link structure and rebuild it which causes issues.

What are some good admin_menu alternatives that provide very similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you may use [admin](https://drupal.org/project/admin) module in combination with [coffee](https://drupal.org/project/coffee)